# IsDBNull in a IIf statement

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code:

```
<div class="featpropv3_price"><span class="featpropv3_price_o"><%# IIf(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency"), "")%></span> <span class="featpropv3_price_r"><%# iif(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0,formatnumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount"),0,0,0,-1),"POA") %></span>
```

I want to check if its equal to IsDBNull

I have tried :

```
IIf(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0 or DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount" IsDBNull.
```

What I want to do is if it is 0 or IsDBNull i want to show POA.

EDIT:

I think I will need something like:

```
<%# IIf(Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")),  if( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency"), "")%>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What VB.NET version are you using? Also, the title suggests that you mean `If` but actually it's the `IIf` function. If you use .NET 3.5(VS 2008) or higher you can (and should) use the `If`-operator instead(which is not the `If...Then...Else`-statement).

Comment: Version 2008: .NET 3.5(VS 2008)

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no acceptable 'Eval' excepts this number of arguments

Comment: Have you simply tried `If(Eval("amount") IsNot Nothing, Eval("amount"), "POA")`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using IIF.  IIF is a FUNCTION that takes three arguments and returns one -- it isn't useful for avoiding null derefernces. You should instead be using the IF operator that was introduced with VB2008.  The IF operator is an actual operator, and it does not evaluate the "false" branch unless it is required to.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IsDBNull` function. And use `AndAlso` to ensure short-circuit evaluation

```
<div class="featpropv3_price">
    <span class="featpropv3_price_o">
        <%# IIf(Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")) AndAlso DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency").ToString(), "")%>
     </span> 
    <span class="featpropv3_price_r">
        <%# iif(Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")) AndAlso DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0, formatnumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount").ToString(),0,0,0,-1),"POA") %>
    </span>
```

UPDATE:

Calling `ToString()` is because (unlike `:?` in C#, VB's `Iif` is a function and the runtime should evaluate all the parameters before passing them and if you don't call `ToString()` you'll get an `InvalidCastException` on the second `Iif`.

UPATE 2:

OK. I re-wrote it with just If:

```
<div class="featpropv3_price">
    <span class="featpropv3_price_o">
        <%If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")) AndAlso DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0 Then%>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency")%>
        <% Else %>
            <%= ""%>
        <% End If%>
     </span> 
    <span class="featpropv3_price_r">
        <% If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")) AndAlso DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0%>
            <%# formatnumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount").ToString(),0,0,0,-1)%>
        <% Else %>
            <%= "POA" %>
        <%End If%>
    </span>
```

Comment: Just asking why the same line twice

Comment: Maybe because you shouldn't show the `currency` if there is no `amount` present for this row. That is the first `Iif`. The second `Iif` will show the `amount` itself.

Comment: I still get an error on my site: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Currency' is not valid.

Comment: I made a mistake. You should use `AndAlso`. Updated the answer. Really sorry about that.

Comment: Please check my original post for update. Still getting error.

Comment: yes till a error about DBNull. I think it needs to be ,but not sure how to code it : `<%# IIf(Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")),  if( DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency"), "")%>`

Comment: on above i get a error : Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: That is not what I told you to do! You should not put that `if` inside an exression

Comment: I put a `ToString()` for the first one too. That will solve the problem

Comment: my exact code at the moment that gives the error as you suggested: `<div class="featpropv3_price"><span class="featpropv3_price_o"><%# IIf(Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")) AndAlso DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency"), "")%></span><span class="featpropv3_price_r"><%# iif(Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount")) AndAlso DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount") <> 0, formatnumber(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "amount").ToString(),0,0,0,-1),"POA") %></span>`

Comment: Change `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency")` to `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "currency").ToString()`

Comment: Same error:
http://www.keageoz.co.za/property_search_result.aspx?country_ref=0&province_ref=0&town_ref=0&suburb_ref=0&type=13&sort=1&from=0&to=1000000000&status=0&beds=0&baths=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57843/discussion-between-alireza-and-user3458266).